# how to display data from a table in php using checkbox?

Tags: php, database

I have multiple themes in my database and my query is to fetch the common info of these themes by selecting `check boxes` in php?
suppose there are four themes `'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd'` I have separate tables too containing there common data i.e. a table of `a intersect b, a intersect c and a intersect d` and so on.

now what i have tried is first user have to select the theme form a drop box , then will select the multiple comparing themes using check box. When i check two themes it displays the data of last theme only.

```
<form method="GET" action="abc.php" name="form">
   <font size = "4px", color = "#008C9A", align = "left"><b> Select Theme >> </b></font>    
   <select name ="table[]">
     <option value="ab">a</option>
     <option value="bc">b</option>
     <option value="cd">c</option>
   <br/>
   <font size="4px" color="#008C9A" align="centre">
    <b> Show Common Genes of Selected Theme with </b>
   </font> <br/> <br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="search" value = "a"/> 
    <font color = "#2F4F4F"><b>a </b></font>                         
   <input type="checkbox" name="search" value = "a"/>
    <font color = "#2F4F4F"><b>b</b></font>                       
   <input type="checkbox" name="search"/ value = "c"> 
    <font color = "#2F4F4F"><b>c</b></font>                         
   <input type= "submit" value= "Search" name="sub" /> 
</form>
```

can any one suggest me what should be my action.php?

i am trying this but it is giving no results:

```
    <?php
    require("config.php");

    $table=$_POST['table'];
    $search=$_POST['search'];

  echo"<table border='0', width='1200', align='center'>
<tr>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Theme</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Id</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Symbol</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Name</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Synonyms</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Chromosome</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>New_Id</font></th>

</tr>";

        foreach($search as $key)
        {

switch($key)
            {
      case"cancer":         
   $sql = mysql_query("select * from $table where theme = 'cancer'", $con);
    $num_row=mysql_num_rows($sql);


    for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
{

$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);


  echo"<tr bgcolor = '#EBDDE2'>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['theme'] ."</b></font></td>";

    $strName2 = $result["Locus_id"];
   echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['id'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['symbol'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['name'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['Synonyms'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['Chromosome'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['new_id'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"</tr>";
}
    break;          

    case"diabetes":         
   $sql = mysql_query("select * from $table where theme = 'diabetes'", $con);
    $num_row=mysql_num_rows($sql);


    for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
{

$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo"<tr bgcolor = '#EBDDE2'>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['theme'] ."</b></font></td>";

    $strName2 = $result["Locus_id"];
   echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['id'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['symbol'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['name'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['Synonyms'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['Chromosome'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['new_id'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"</tr>";
}
}
    break;          

            case"tubersulosis":         
   $sql = mysql_query("select * from $table where theme = 'tuberculosis'", $con);
    $num_row=mysql_num_rows($sql);


    for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
{

$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo"<tr bgcolor = '#EBDDE2'>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['theme'] ."</b></font></td>";

    $strName2 = $result["Locus_id"];
   echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['id'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['symbol'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['name'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['Synonyms'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['Chromosome'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['new_id'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"</tr>";
}
}
    break;
            case"hiv":          
   $sql = mysql_query("select * from $table where theme = 'HIV'", $con);
    $num_row=mysql_num_rows($sql);


    for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
{

$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo"<tr bgcolor = '#EBDDE2'>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['theme'] ."</b></font></td>";

    $strName2 = $result["Locus_id"];
   echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['id'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['symbol'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['name'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['Synonyms'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['Chromosome'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"<td align=center><font color = 'purple'><b>" . $result['new_id'] ."</b></font></td>";
  echo"</tr>";
}
}
    break;
        }
            }

mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Use name="search[]" instead of just search

Comment: value for second checkbox should be `b`. you are using same value in first two checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @manoj change the name to `search[]` instead of `search`. And make the form method to `POST`.

Now in abc.php you can get the checkbox value by

```
$search = $_POST['search'];//this will be an array
```

The rest i think you can do. right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your form code should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="abc.php" name="form"> <!-- You can keep GET as well -->
   <font size="4px" color="#008C9A" align="left"><!-- no impact but extra , removed-->
    <b> Select Theme >> </b>
   </font>    
   <select name="table"> <!-- why using [] if multiple option can't be selected -->
    <option value="ab">a</option>
    <option value="bc">b</option>
    <option value="cd">c</option>
   </select> <!-- Important: missing close select tag -->
   <br/>
   <font size="4px" color="#008C9A" align="center">
    <b> Show Common Genes of Selected Theme with </b>
   </font> <br/> <br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="a" /> <!-- name should use [] notation if multiple values -->
    <font color = "#2F4F4F"><b>a </b></font>                         
   <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="b" /> <!-- Note value change here -->
    <font color="#2F4F4F"><b>b</b></font>                       
   <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="c" /> <!-- extra / removed -->
    <font color="#2F4F4F"><b>c</b></font>                         
   <input type="submit" value="Search" name="sub" /> 
</form>
```

In your PHP file, you can access values:

```
$search = $_POST['search']; // checkbox values
print_r($search);

$table = $_POST['table']; // select value
echo $table;
```

Comment: actually my problem is if i check multiple check boxes its gives value of only last one.
i have used 
$search = $_POST['search'];
select * from table where theme = ". $search ."'

Comment: Your SQL should be `"select * from table where theme = '".implode(",", $search) ."'"`

Comment: thanx apul but it is also not working. In fact it is giving no output.

Comment: can you use `print_r($search);` Also did you replaced your HTML to my provided one? your HTML had some issues.

Comment: yup i have corrected my html page according to yours. but where to use print_r($search)

Comment: i really need help as i want to submit ma assignment asap. i have tried a lot but last where i reach is d extraction of only one theme not all.

Comment: am i able to make you understand my question?

Comment: just before you use in query, `print_r($search);` It will help you finding issues. However, if you need more clear help, share your full code.

Comment: link?? for database??

Comment: somehow show me your full code & database schema. That's it.

Comment: what i need is actually i have five tables one for cancer one for diabetes and so on. one table consists common genes with other themes. for eg cancer_common_genes table has data for genes of cancer common in diabetes, tb and hiv. and the columns in table are theme which contains theme in which common genes found and their corresponding genes so each table contains all themes with their corresponding genes. what all i want is if user want to search the common genes form multiple themes first he need to select from dropdown then check the boxes to get list of common genes from selected table